# spark-redshift unload data. Directory name and save in CSV

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I got problem with spark-redshift lib from databricks. Actually I have 2 questions.

1. How I can UNLOAD data in .csv format with headers?
2. How I can set CUSTOM directory name ? By that I mean ignore those random numbers

> INFO RedshiftRelation: UNLOAD ('SELECT "companynumber", "companyname" FROM (select companynumber,companyname from cf_core.company) ') TO 's3://xxx/Spark/6b70cb07-9499-4442-8e3a-335f2cb2c8ae/' WITH CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/somerole' ESCAPE MANIFEST

```
    val companiesData = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    .option("url","jdbc:redshift://xxxx:5439/cf?user="+user+"&password="+password)
    .option("query","select companynumber,companyname from cf_core.company")
    //.option("dbtable",schema+"."+table)
    .option("aws_iam_role","arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/somerole")
    .option("tempdir","s3a://xxxxx/Spark")
    .load()
```

Thank you for help and answers !